# How can I check check-boxes according to value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How can I check check-boxes (on page load) according to value of check-boxes using jQuery? I have list of values that I have stored within localstorage (Long live HTML5 !!) A sample data would be

```
something_random|something_random2|something_random3
```

And basically I want to read each value and make sure onload checkboxes that already have those values are checked.

I have already written;

```
my_cookie=localStorage.getItem('chosen_ones');

      $.each(my_cookie.split("|"), function(index, values) {
               if((values==val)&&(values!=null)&&(values!="")&&(values!="null")&&(values!="")){
                 $('input[value='+values+'').attr('checked', true);
            }
        });
```

However this didn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][value='+values+']').attr('checked', true);
```

Notice the type, and the closing ']'.

Comment: sorry I edited my post a little late. can you help me with this new situation?

Comment: I'm using 


$(':checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function(){
    val= $(this).val();
      $.each(my_cookie.split("|"), function(index, values) {
               if((values==val)&&(values!=null)&&(values!="")&&(values!="null")&&(values!="")){
                 $('input[type=checkbox][value='+values+']').attr('checked', true);
            }
        });
});

However this time it just freezes why that may be?

Comment: The query already selects all the checkboxes with the appropriate values by itself, so the $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').each is not useful here. The $.each(my_cookie...) loop should be enough.

Comment: yes but my "val" is the value of the check box I only want to check the check box if both values mach (i.e. the value from the local storage and the value of the checkbox match)

Comment: This is what the [value='+values+']' does: select only the checkboxes that match the value.